# Docker after 21.04 update runninng on /run/docker.sock

Tags: docker, 21.04

After updating Ubuntu to 21.04 from 20.10 docker seems to be running in:

```
/run/docker.sock
```

but the docker client goes to look for it on:

```
/var/run/docker.sock
```

How can I fix this?

Elaborating a bit, running a docker command I get:

```
$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

But the docker service seems to be running with the docker socket in another location (out of `var`):

```
$ sudo systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-05-17 10:14:49 CEST; 5s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 10163 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 18
     Memory: 40.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─10163 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

may 17 10:14:49 xps-laptop dockerd[10163]: time="2021-05-17T10:14:49.599580310+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support CPU realtime scheduler"
may 17 10:14:49 xps-laptop dockerd[10163]: time="2021-05-17T10:14:49.599624934+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight"
may 17 10:14:49 xps-laptop dockerd[10163]: time="2021-05-17T10:14:49.599642841+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight_device"
may 17 10:14:49 xps-laptop dockerd[10163]: time="2021-05-17T10:14:49.599907138+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
may 17 10:14:49 xps-laptop dockerd[10163]: time="2021-05-17T10:14:49.740160234+02:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be use>
may 17 10:14:49 xps-laptop dockerd[10163]: time="2021-05-17T10:14:49.838137738+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
may 17 10:14:49 xps-laptop dockerd[10163]: time="2021-05-17T10:14:49.854381886+02:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=20.10.2-0ubuntu2 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.2
may 17 10:14:49 xps-laptop dockerd[10163]: time="2021-05-17T10:14:49.854462072+02:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
may 17 10:14:49 xps-laptop systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
may 17 10:14:49 xps-laptop dockerd[10163]: time="2021-05-17T10:14:49.879020578+02:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
```

Edit (content of `/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket`):

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket
[Unit]
Description=Docker Socket for the API

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/docker.sock
SocketMode=0660
SocketUser=root
SocketGroup=docker

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Edit 2 (content of `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`):

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network-online.target firewalld.service containerd.service
Wants=network-online.target
Requires=docker.socket
Wants=containerd.service

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always

# Note that StartLimit* options were moved from "Service" to "Unit" in systemd 229.
# Both the old, and new location are accepted by systemd 229 and up, so using the old location
# to make them work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitBurst=3

# Note that StartLimitInterval was renamed to StartLimitIntervalSec in systemd 230.
# Both the old, and new name are accepted by systemd 230 and up, so using the old name to make
# this option work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitInterval=60s

# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity

# Comment TasksMax if your systemd version does not support it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this option.
TasksMax=infinity

# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes

# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process
OOMScoreAdjust=-500

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What is the output of your docker.socket file? Please list it: `/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket` The entry "ListenStream" should match, so I would think this should be set to `/var/run/docker.sock` if it's not. And then restart your services.

Comment: Also make sure that the directory `/var` has a symlink to `run -> /run` - so `/var/run` is actually a symlink to `/run`.

Comment: Thanks @ArturMeinild : `/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket` has actually `/var/run/docker.sock` on it. So that explains why the client goes there, but that symlink exists as well, so I don't know why it isn't going to `/run`. 

An `ls /var/run/docker.sock` certifies that the socket is there.

Comment: What does your `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file say - can you list it in the OP? Notably the "ExecStart" entry.

Comment: You could also try to make the docker daemon listen on port 2375 and see if that helps - follow this guide: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-73-connecting-to-a-remote-docker-daemon (basically to add `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` to the "ExecStart" entry.

Comment: I've added the content of `/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket` to the OP. There is no "ExecStart" entry :-(.

Comment: That's undestandable - the "ExecStart" is in `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` - try and add that as well. :-)

Comment: Ouch, sorry. Added now.

Comment: Ok, it looks exactly like mine. But I'm on 20.04, so I don't really know anything more about issues on 21.04. But maybe try my suggestion about adding `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` to the "ExecStart" entry and see if that helps.

Comment: Following the guide you sent me, @ArturMeinild I did initially a different change, changing in the "ExecStart" entry the part `-H fd://` to be `unix://` and that has made the trick. `docker ps -a` now works, it doesn't see my previous containers, coz a different change from aufs to overlay2, but it sees two containers from 6 months ago (maybe from when I had updated to 20.10). Thank you very much @artur-meinild

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, check that the symlink in `/var/run` is in place and pointing to `/run` (it appears this was ok in your case).

Next, try changing the "ExecStart" statement by creating a Drop-In config:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/options.conf
```

Now add the following to the file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/options.conf`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

Now reload systemd config and reload docker daemon:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

If you also want the daemon to listen on a remote port, add `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` to the "ExecStart" entry in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/options.conf`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

However, it appears in your case that changing to `-H unix://` did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting the `docker.socket` service or rebooting the system if that is an option:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker.socket
```